# WebHandler ASHX .NET compiler error : must implement IsReusable matching ReadOnly/WriteOnly

Tags: asp.net, ashx

I've been tasked to add a web handler to a legacy website written in VB.NET/ASP.NET about 8 years ago, working with .NET framework 1.1.4322.

I do not understand why I'm getting this error message:

`Compiler Error Message: BC30154: 'Foo' must implement 'Overridable ReadOnly Property IsReusable() as Boolean' for interface 'System.Web.IHttpHandler'. Implementing property must have matching 'ReadOnly/WriteOnly' specifiers`

Here is my code:

```
<%@ WebHandler language="VB" class="Foo" %>
Imports System
Imports System.Web

Public Class Foo 
 Implements IHttpHandler

Public Sub ProcessRequest(context as HttpContext)
  Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
     'TO DO: Write request handling code here
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property IsReusable() as Boolean 
Implements IHttpHandler.IsReusable
  Get
   Return False
  End Get
End Property

End Class
```

I've also tried `ReadOnly Overrides Property IsReusable()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the `IsReusable` Property as `Overridable` not `Overrides`.

Comment: I think it was a different dumb error on my part: the `Implements...` must be on the same line as the Sub and Property declarations, but on the line below the class declaration.

Comment: in VB if you have the same statement on the next line you must use the line conteuation token `_`